# Undefined property error before store gets populated by API call

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

In my child component, I'm trying to access a nested property (called `background_color`) of a store state object (called `template`) :

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="btn"
    :style="{ 'background-color': backgroundColor }"
  >
    content
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      backgroundColor: state => state.template.button_branding.secondary_button.background_color
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

The store is populated from the parent view component with a store action call:

```js
created () {
  this.initializeStore()
},
```

In my store, this action is defined thus:

```js
export const actions = {
  initializeStore ({ state, commit }, data) {
    this.$axios.get('path.to.api.endpoint')
      .then((res) => {
        commit('setConfig', res.data) // populates store
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'secondary_button' of undefined

Yet I see my nested property populated in the state via Vue DevTools.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use optional chaining combined with nullish coalescing to add a default value like this:

`backgroundColor: state => state.template?.button_branding?.secondary_button?.background_color ?? 'default_value'`

This should protect against errors while the API is being called.

Also, it might be neater to move your logic into a `getter` inside the store, and set the default value there:

```
getters: {
  backgroundColor: state => {
    return state.template?.button_branding?.secondary_button?.background_color ?? 'default_value'`;
  }
}
```

That way the component can use `mapGetters` and it doesn't need to care whether or not the default value is being used.

Comment: Wow, that works thanks! I've never seen anything like this, I definitely learnt something today :) I'm wondering though. This problem of mine seems extremely basic, actually I suspect the majority of large Vue project run into it. Is there not a standard or idiomatic way of addressing it?

Comment: Using a default value while waiting for the API call is the standard approach IMO, but there are multiple ways of achieving this. For example you could fully instantiate your state so that the property already exists - with a default value - before the data is fetched, but I think that would be less neat since you are dealing with a deeply-nested property here. I have updated my answer with a further suggestion.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, setting default values is indeed common. It is only when the state is very complex hence populated dynamically that this type of problem arises.
Anyway thank you very much.